# simple heterogeneous k-ary tree in java (for creating network simulator)

Tags: java, tree, adt

I am working on a project to create a network simulator. The networks I am simulating are hierarchical networks. I am using a k-ary tree data structure, with some extra methods to simulate and perform some analysis of the networks.

So far, I have a generic k-ary tree data structure that accepts generic types, it works fine. The problem is that the tree nodes can only seem to be of one type. For instance, if I declare the tree with type String the nodes must all be String objects.

However, since I am trying to model a computer network (or any network), some nodes might have to be server objects and some nodes might be host objects, or even router object etc...

I want my heterogeneous tree's nodes to have some server objects and some mobileDevice objects...

I am not finding too many answers to this on Google, and it seems to be testing my creativity. I do know of an abstract syntax tree builder called ANTL3R or something, it supposedly can utilize heterogeneous trees, but my tree is for networks, not compilers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this is to define an `interface` that all nodes of the tree must implement. Then you can declare your tree to store data of that type.

```
public interface ComputerComponent {
    String getName();
    ComponetType getType();
    ...
}

Tree<ComputerComponent> network;
```

The other alternative (not recommended) is to declare it to be `Tree<Object>`. Then you can store anything in it but you lose all type checking capabilities and will end up having to use `instanceof` and casts to use the data you retrieve.

Comment: So, my node class would be an interface, with variables String getName()  componentType getType()... I assume, that when I actually addNode() to the tree I can add the node 'Server Implements ComputerComponent', and whenever I use toString() on the node I will get the object name back?

Comment: Your answer is essentially correct, its the same method the compilers use for building the abstract syntax tree. However I have decided to go for a way cheaper route.  What I do is make each node a String object, and I use the charAt() method to read the first char, if it is a 1, it is a server, if it is a 2, it is a host.... charAt() in the 2nd place could be delay, and I have a cheap scheme for this